# Excel using too much memory when repeatedly running macro with application.ontime

Tags: vba, excel

I know very little about VBA but I made a macro which runs every 15 minutes that just adds a new row to the worksheet which contains the values from the first row (which are rtd functions). The longer I have this running, the more memory excel uses and after 24 hours it is using 1gb+ of RAM. Is there anyway I can improve this or stop this from happening so I can run the code for days? Thanks

```
Sub Store()
currow = Workbooks("Store data.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Workbooks("Store data.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(currow + 1, 1) = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy HH:nn:ss")

Workbooks("Store data.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1"). _
   Range(Workbooks("Store data.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(currow + 1, 2), _
    Workbooks("Store data.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(currow + 1, 47)) = _
    Workbooks("Store data.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1"). _
    Range(Workbooks("Store data.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2), _
    Workbooks("Store data.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 47)).Value

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"), "Store"
End Sub
```

Comment: What's with the `Store data.xlsm` ? Is it some other workbook?

Comment: Is this the only `Application.OnTime` statement in the entire project?

Comment: rtd functions?  real time data, which library?  that looks like most likely culprit.

Comment: Have you tried leaving the workbook open for that length of time *without* the macro running?

Comment: in light of what @SMeaden said, what if you run the code once manually. How much does size increase with new row of data. Also, what if you try it from a blank workbook with one line of data and then run it. How much does it increase then?

Comment: @Gene that is just the workbook. Should it not be there?

Comment: @YowE3K  this is the entire project to yes

Comment: @SMeaden yes real time data but I have used rtd formulas forever without any memory issues. It has only started when I started to run this code.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes it works fine when it isn't running.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman How would I test this? I now very little about VBA and I don't know how I even got it to work to begin with lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From earlier experiments I also found that the `Application.OnTime` is not supposed to call itself (it needs to call a separate procedure), and the recursion to be handled in a different way

Try these 2 versions:

---

**V1 - Application.OnTime**

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateStore()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"), "Store"
End Sub

Public Sub Store()
    Dim curRow As Long, firstRow As Range, lastRow As Range

    With Workbooks("Store data.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
        curRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(curRow, 1) = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy HH:nn:ss")

        Set firstRow = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(2, 47))
        Set lastRow = .Range(.Cells(curRow, 2), .Cells(curRow, 47))
    End With
    lastRow = firstRow.Value
    UpdateStore    'recursive call
End Sub
```

---

**V2 - Sleep API (Edited - Non recursive)**

---

```
Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then      'Win64=true, Win32=true, Win16= false
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#ElseIf Win32 Then  'Win32=true, Win16=false
    Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "Kernel32" Alias "Sleep" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If

Public Sub StoreSleepAPI()
    Dim curRow As Long, firstRow As Range, lastRow As Range, counter As Long

    For counter = 1 To 400    '<-- adjust this to "how many hours" * "4" ( times / hour)

        With Workbooks("Store data.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
            curRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Cells(curRow, 1) = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy HH:nn:ss")

            Set firstRow = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(2, 47))
            Set lastRow = .Range(.Cells(curRow, 2), .Cells(curRow, 47))
        End With

        lastRow = firstRow.Value
        Sleep 900000    '1000 = 1 second, 900000 = 15 minutes
        DoEvents
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Sleep is using less CPU as well

Comment: Great it seems to be doing it's job. I'll let this run overnight and I will give an update in the morning.

Comment: I ran V1 overnight and I am still having the same issue. This morning it was using over 1gb of RAM compared to normally just 120mb. Perhaps the issue isn't the macro? I will leave it open today without the code running and I will see if I still have the problem.

Comment: Your V2 is **truly** recursive - i.e. you are continuing to add extra layers to the call stack every iteration.  That will definitely crash after a while.  (A simple test where sub `x` called sub `y` which called sub `x` crashed for me, with an "out of stack space" error, after 3405 iterations.  That was with no variables within the `Sub`s - the more variables used, the quicker it crashes.)

Comment: I just made an update to V2 - **please use this new version - V2 - Sleep API (Edited - Non recursive)**, and adjust the number of iterations according to your needs - it shouldn't increase the memory usage

Comment: @YowE3K - thanks for the very useful feedback - I never checked what I should have!, so I made important changes to version 2 based on your comment

Comment: @AndrewK Please see edits made by Paul to his V2 answer.  (Paul, I don't think the OP sees comments left on your answer unless you ping them, so hopefully this will draw their attention to the update.)

Comment: Hey. So I ran the workbook without the VBA code running and I was still having the same problem. The workbook has only RTD fuctions and some 6 charts where the series are stored as "names" which automatically update to include new data as my VBA script runs. Could either the RTD functions or the names be causing excel to use increasing amounts of ram?

Comment: That's what it seems like; not sure about the names but I never tested it. See if you can disable the RTDs and just leave the names updating for a few hours. If you do find which one of the 2 is causing the issue please post it here as an answer - it might be helpful to others in the future

Answer (score 1):

I assume, based on you explicit identification of the objects involved that the `Sub Store()` is in a general module. If not, make sure it is declared `Public` and mod the call in `Sub b()` below appropriately.

You need to separate the action from the recall. Place two subs in a general module (EDITED - I mixed them up earlier on):

```
 Public Sub a()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"), "b" 
 End Sub

 Public Sub b()
    Call Store
 End Sub
```

Replace the `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"), "Store"` in your `Sub Store()` with `Call a`. That's it.

The `OnTime` works when it is in a General module (not in an Object module, e.g. a Worksheet module). Also, it should call a sub in a General module (Insert --> Module). I just know this works (took me a while to figure this out long time ago). In addition, this arrangement allows the "Store" routine to finish running and VBA engine to clear out the memory it used to run the "Store".

Still, do not just trust me (or yourself either): always test!

Comment: Perhaps add a bit of explanation as to why pushing a line of code down two procedure calls will solve the memory issue.  (I'm afraid I'm not seeing how it will help, so there is a good chance that the OP won't understand the reasoning either.)

Comment: @Gene Yes it is in the general module. I don't know what that means but it was the only way I could get it to work. I will try your suggestion with the two subs but can you explain how it will change things?

Comment: I think this answer is going in the right direction because the OP might be causing a recursive call when it's not supposed to. I'll provide another answer with this actual implementation of the OP, and a new version using the Sleep API

Comment: @paul bica: **Sleep** API is easy to use but it has **obvious problems**: 1) It Freezes the entire process (Excel does not respond); 2) There is no way to stop the Sleep function. Th VBA's Wait function does not have these shortcomings, unless you need time intervals under 1 sec, which it cannot do.

Comment: FWIW - I have been running two instances of Excel (one with the original method where the statement to set the next scheduled event is within the same subroutine which will be later called, and one where the scheduling statement is in a procedure called by the scheduled event) for over three hours, with the scheduled event running every minute, and both still show the same amount of memory being used.